# Haskell: fmap on nested functors

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

What is the way to abstract mapping a function over a list of functors?

I understand the basic applicative

```
λ: [(+2),(*2)] <*> [10,20]
[12,22,20,40]
```

but how do I handle
`[(+2),(*2)] ???? [Just 10, Just 20]`?

all the ways I can think of seem really convoluted.

for example:

```
λ: (<$>) <$> [(+2),(*2)]  <*> [Just 10, Just 20]
[Just 12,Just 22,Just 20,Just 40]
```

Comment: IMO `fmap <$> [(+2),(*2)]  <*> [Just 10, Just 20]` is not too bad. Generally, the traditional way to abstract over (specific) nested functors is to write them as monad transformer stacks, but I doubt that makes sense for your application.

Comment: @leftaroundabout have you got a good place for me to learn about monad transformers?

Comment: [RWS's section about them isn't too bad](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html). But again, writing this example in `MaybeT []` is probably not sensible. `Compose` is better already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Data.Functor.Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) to treat nested Functors/Applicatives as a single Functor/Applicative:

```
ghci> import Data.Functor.Compose
ghci> getCompose (Compose [pure (+2), pure (*2)] <*> Compose [Just 10, Just 20])
[Just 12,Just 22,Just 20,Just 40]
```

But perhaps the (`Compose`, `getCompose`) newtype noise is not worth it in this case.

Comment: That is useful thanks I will read up on those two functions. However in this specific case... I think the `pure` noise is more of an issue ... rather than write `pure` for each function wouldn't it be easier to write  `[((+2) <$>),((*2) <$>)] <*> [Just 10, Just 20]`?

Comment: @matthias `[((+2) <$>),((*2) <$>)]` looks confusing to me.  leftaroundabout's answer seems to be the most legible.

Answer (score 2):

To me, a quick `do` block is more readable:

```
t2 = do f <- fs
        m <- ms
        pure (f <$> m)
```

Comment: I think that that is quite elegant